# Adobe Flash Builder: visual components aren't displayed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, adobe, flash-builder

I stuck. I've been trying to get working simple app with `Adobe Flash Builder` but with no luck.

It's pretty simple and I even didn't get visual elements such as `button` to be displayed on any kind of simulator/devices.

I followed by some video tutorial and seems like configured everything right, no errors appeared but the problem is that when I launch app on `device/simulator/air` `iOS/Android` even real `iOS` device - it remains blank.... empty. Just white screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160"
               applicationComplete="init(event)">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button id="button1" x="100" y="58" label="300ms"/>   
    <s:Button id="button2" x="200" y="58" label="500ms"/>
    <s:Button id="button3" x="300" y="58" label="1000ms"/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Vibration;

            private var vibrate:Vibration

            private function init(evt:Event):void
            {
                trace("We are here");

                if(Vibration.isSupported)
                {
                    setupButtons();
                } else {
                    trace("Vibration is not supported");
                }                           
            }

            private function setupButtons():void
            {
                button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtons);
                button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtons);
                button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleButtons);

                vibrate = new Vibration();
            }

            private function handleButtons(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                switch (event.currentTarget.id)
                {
                    case "button1":
                        vibrate.vibrate(300);
                        break;
                    case "button2":
                        vibrate.vibrate(500);
                        break;
                    case "button3":
                        vibrate.vibrate(1000);
                        break;                  
                }

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
</s:Application>
```

At least 3 buttons should appear. No useful information while debugging in console, no stopping on breakpoints in -init() method.

[image]

I'm pretty frustrated about my first meeting `flash builder` and developing for mobile platforms.
Flash Builder 4.7

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get the trace message when debugging? It could be some exception that prevents the application to finish initializing(try commenting all your init code and keep only the mxml and see if you get the buttons)

Comment: no, I'm not getting any debug info

Comment: It works if I remove <script> section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is a crash in the initialize code, try removing all the lines , then when works add one by one the script lines back until you find the issue.

Comment: I'm trying to do that... Empty init() method with just trace line works fine

Comment: ty, but I don't know if I should accept this answer, because it's not answer itself. Looks more like comment...

Comment: @Injectios it is hard for me to find the problematic line, even if I would use the exact same code it could not happen here(I may have different versions of stuff) but the answer that is an error in the init function was correct this pointed you in the right direction aand in 5 minutes you could get back to me with the problematic line and I can help more

Comment: that was problem for me as well

Comment: ok, so empty screen is caused by importing Vibration extension. But I imported it in correct way I hope

Comment: @Injectios now you can get all the info about the Vibratipon extension and the error and make a new question with all the details

Comment: thank guys, I don't need to move forward with Vibration extension, moreover it is still unclear why it causes empty screen, I've checked twice - everything is correct

Comment: @Injectios I do not have experience with native extensions, so make a new question  for this issue with all the details,how did you setup it and someone with more experience may have a idea on how to debug it